# Provide alternate path to scrapy xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm just getting started with Scrapy and trying to pull down the home team, away team and score from http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/results/ as a way to learn.

Everything works fine, except that the xpath I am using to fetch the teams is reliant on an 'a' tag:

```
match.xpath('.//*[@class="team-home teams"]/a/text()').extract_first()
```

Some of the teams do not have a link, and so the query is occasionally returning None.

The following xpath drops the /a/ and picks up the un-linked teams, but also a lot of newline strings:

```
match.xpath('.//*[@class="team-home teams"]/text()').extract_first()
```

How can I modify my code to provide an alternative xpath if None is returned? Or is there a smarter xpath that will return the correct result regardless of an 'a' tag existing?

```
import scrapy


class FootballresultsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "footballResults"
    start_urls = ['http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/results/']

    def parse(self, response):

        for match in response.xpath('//td[@class="match-details"]'):
            yield {
                'home_team': match.xpath('.//*[@class="team-home teams"]/a/text()').extract_first(),
                'score': match.xpath('.//span[@class="score"]/abbr/text()').extract_first(),
                'away_team': match.xpath('.//*[@class="team-away teams"]/a/text()').extract_first(),
            }
```

*** EDIT ***

Below is the code attempting to use '|' between xpaths, but still returns None for any entries with no anchor tag. I'm only demonstrating with a single entry, `home`, for brevity.

```
import scrapy

class ResultsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "results"
    #allowed_domains = ["www.bbc.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/results/']

    def parse(self, response):

        match_details = response.xpath('//td[@class="match-details"]')

        for match in match_details:

            a_xpath = './/span[@class="team-home teams"]/a/text()'
            text_xpath = './/span[@class="team-home teams"]/a/text()'


            home = match.xpath(a_xpath + ' | ' + text_xpath).extract_first()

            yield {
                'Home': home
            }
```

Below is the code that works, although it's a bit long winded and I'm sure there's a much neater way to do it.

```
import scrapy


class ResultsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "results"
    #allowed_domains = ["www.bbc.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/results/']

    def parse(self, response):

        match_details = response.xpath('//td[@class="match-details"]')

        for match in match_details:

            if match.xpath('.//span[@class="team-home teams"]/a/text()').extract_first() == None:
                home = match.xpath('.//span[@class="team-home teams"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
            else:
                home = match.xpath('.//span[@class="team-home teams"]/a/text()').extract_first()

            yield {
                'Home': home,
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the  `|`  operator in xpath:

```
first_xpath = './/*[@class="team-home teams"]/a/text()'
second_xpath = ... # The alternative xpath
match.xpath(first_xpath + ' | ' + second_xpath).extract_first()
```

Comment: Thanks @VMRuiz. I can't get this working though. Is the idea that if first_xpath resolves to None, then the second_xpath is used? I'll edit my post with the code I attempted, and also the method I used to get the scraping to work, although it's a bit long-winded.

Comment: @itzafugazi You set the same value for `a_xpath ` and `text_xpath`, that's why it always returns None to you.

Comment: Ah, you are right, bad copy/pasting, thanks. Anyway I'm going to stick with the if/else method, because in this case I also need the `strip()` at the end of only the non-linked results.

Answer (score 0):

Answering from my phone so haven't tried it yet.

Option 1: Regular expression

Option 2: use item loader.

```
l = ItemLoader(TeamItem(), response = response)

l.add_xpath('name', '//your_first_xpath')
l.add_xpath('name', '//your_second_xpath')
```

Then in your item class you can drop unqualified names